# Actual pixel dimensions of retina images (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, retina-display

After reading Apple's own HIG (specifically the 'Creating images for retina..' section) and looking at similar answers and suggested blogs - I can't seem to get a good solid fix on how properly design images for retina.

To best explain, let me set up a scenario:

- I have a UIButton that is 44 x 44 points that I laid out in IB.
- I go to photoshop, create an image that is 44 x 44 pixels. I save that as image@2x.png
- I save another, without the @2x.png appended on the file name.
- In the code, I do something like ... `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]`

From what I have read, it seems that DPI doesn't matter. I do also understand that retina images are, of course, double in scale to the original image. So for the scenario above, was the `image@2x.png` supposed to be **88 x 88 pixels** instead of **44 x 44 pixels**? In the `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]`, do I need to specify the `@2x` in the image's name, or does xcode take care of that?

Going with the scenario I described above, can someone **either correct me** or **confirm that this is the correct pixel dimensions** the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenario you described is wrong.

Here are the right:

1. Assume you want a 44pt x 44pt button to place in IB;
2. Go to Photoshop create a 88px x 88px image named with @2x;
3. Create another image that 44px x 44px without addition @2x;
4. In your IB or code, set the image use normal name, which without @2x
   in the image name. System will display the normal image and @2x
   image properly.

Comment: Perfect, that's all I needed. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

To create button which IB size is 44x44 you need two images:

1. Image.png which size is 44x44
2. Image@2x.png which size is 88x88

iOS will automatically choose proper file when you use the base name

To load that image in code you simply use line below:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"]
```

and again, iOS will get proper image

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the naming conventions for UIImage call.

Comment: Mae sure you use the same casing. Sometimes the image can't be loaded. So if the image is named 'MyImage.png' use `imageNamed:@"MyImage"`